# オープンソースのGemのバージョンを上げて欲しい時はどのようなプルリクエストを作成するのか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

自作でGemを公開したことがないのでわからないのですが、
下記2つのバージョン番号を上げて欲しいと思っております。

[mcasimir/devise-i18n-views](https://github.com/mcasimir/devise-i18n-views)
[doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-i18n](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-i18n)

### devise-i18n-viewsの場合

過去のコミットを確認してみると

#### VERSIONという名のファイルを編集

[0.3.6 · mcasimir/devise-i18n-views@6ca3307](https://github.com/mcasimir/devise-i18n-views/commit/6ca330723b6bb232c702c4640eb89c70b6d37efd)

#### .gemspec ファイルの日付とバージョンとコメントが変わっている

[Regenerate gemspec for version 0.3.6 · mcasimir/devise-i18n-views@2eb13aa](https://github.com/mcasimir/devise-i18n-views/commit/2eb13aa0f9664f9d053b0cd7958fae731d92c9e9)

`VERSION`という名前のファイルを編集した後、`.gemspec`という拡張子のファイルに変更が見受けられました。
推測ですが、`VERSION`は手動で変更し、`.gemspec`は何かしらのコマンドで変更したのではないかと思います。(とはいえ手動な気もする....)

### doorkeeper-i18nの場合

`VERSION`というファイルが見当たりません。
`.gemspec`という拡張子のファイルが見当たります。

### 質問まとめ

Q1　どうして`VERSION`というファイルがあるプロジェクトとないプロジェクトがあるのか？
Q2　どうして`.gemspec`の`s.date`があるプロジェクトとないプロジェクトがあるのか？
Q3　`s.date`は手動で変更するのか？
Q4　一般的には `s.version`を書き換えてプルリクエストを送ればよいのか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gemをどうやって作っているかの違いだと思います。`jeweler`だと`VERSION`ファイルをrakeタスクで生成し使用しますが、`bundler`だと出来ません。.gemspecの`s.date`も同じです。

> Q4　一般的には s.versionを書き換えてプルリクエストを送ればよいのか？

なので、使用しているツールの流儀次第だと思います。が、そもそもの話として、バージョンは開発者が恣意的に決める物なので、pull request投げるのは適切なんでしょうか。普通にコードを書き換えたときのpull requestにはバージョンの改変は含めませんよね。

不都合があるのであれば理由をissueとして切っておく、どういうバージョンにするかは開発者に判断してもらう、のほうがいいような気がします。